# How to create a data type containing a list

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a data type class that contains a list:

```
data Test = [Int] deriving(Show)
```

But Haskell can't parse the constructor. What am i doing wrong here and how can I best achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: The data constructor name is missing. You want something like `data Test = Test [Int]` instead.

Comment: you also probably want a `newtype` rather than `data` if your type is simply a wrapper for a list

Comment: `newtype` still needs a data constructor name in front of the `[Int]`.

Comment: yes of course @WillNess, apologies if that wasn't clear

Comment: @RobinZigmond I'm just being needlessly thorough. :) it was a side note really.

Comment: What materials are you using for study?

Comment: I was reading Learn You A Haskell for Great Good. The examples on chapter 7 didn't include lists and some didn't have the constructor name. Should probably have fiddled around with it a bit more before asking, but anyway I have it working with newtype now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### An Answer

You need to include a constructor, which you haven't done.

```
data Test = Test [Int]
```

Consider reviewing Haskell's several type declarations, their use, and their syntax.

### Haskell Type Declarations

**data**

Allows declaration of zero or more **constructor**s each with zero or more **fields**.

**newtype**

Allows declaration of one constructor with one field.  This field is strict.

**type**

Allows creation of a type *alias* which can be textually interchanged with the type to the right of the equals at any use.

**constructor**

Allows creation of a value of the declared type.  Also allows decomposition of values to obtain the individual fields (via pattern matching)

### Examples

**data**

```
data Options = OptionA Int | OptionB Integer | OptionC PuppyAges
      ^           ^     ^      ^        ^        ^         ^
      |           |   Field    |        |        |         |
    type         Constructor   |        |     Constructor  |
                         Constructor   Field              Field
    deriving (Show)

myPuppies = OptionB 1234
```

**newtype**

```
newtype PuppyAges = AgeList [Int] deriving (Show)

myPuppies :: PuppyAges
myPuppies = AgeList [1,2,3,4]
```

Because the types (PuppyAges) and the constructors  (AgeList) are in different namespaces people can and often do use the same name for each, such as `newtype X = X [Int]`.

**type**

```
type IntList = [Int]

thisIsThat :: IntList -> [Int]
thisIsThat x = x
```

**constructor**s (more)

```
option_is_a_puppy_age :: Options -> Bool
option_is_a_puppy_age (OptionC _) = True
option_is_a_puppy_age () = False

option_has_field_of_value :: Options -> Int -> Bool
option_has_field_of_value (OptionA a) x = x == a
option_has_field_of_value (OptionB b) x = fromIntegral x == b
option_has_field_of_value (OptionC (AgeList cs)) x = x `elem` cs

increment_option_a :: Options -> Options
increment_option_a (OptionA a) = OptionA (a+1)
increment_option_a x           = x
```